# Adding Rows by Using INSERT and SELECT with Image row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please, help me insert rows from old database table to new table with variable image file.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Person(Name, Photo)
SELECT OldName, (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\000\'+ OldName +'.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS PersonImage) FROM [DB.Old].[dbo].WritersTbl
```

Problem that I can't use variable **OldName** in image path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Person(Name, Photo)
SELECT OldName, (SELECT PersonImage.* FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\000\'+ OldName +'.jpg', 
SINGLE_BLOB) AS PersonImage) FROM [DB.Old].[dbo].WritersTbl
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it not working. Problem in image path. I want to use variable image path, which depends on OldName column from table.